# schedule the starting time of events as accurately as possible

Tags: real-time

I would like to schedule a series of events such that to about the nearest 5ms, the starting time of event N is t0 + dt*N, where t0 is some arbitrary time after the process starts. If the events were output to a terminal, they would occur regularly without pauses or speedups. If they were noises, it would produce a regular rhythm. This is my first attempt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void fsleep(double t)
{
    time_t sec = floor(t);
    long nsec = 1e9*(t - sec);
    struct timespec s;
    s.tv_sec = sec;
    s.tv_nsec = nsec;
    nanosleep(&s, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0;; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        fsleep(0.334);
    }
}
```

It is total garbage, even at realtime priority (`nice -n -20`). There are noticeable jitters the entire time, with pauses of up to 1 second, after which a whole bunch of numbers are printed in a row. To test whether it was my terminal, I made the following script:

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdin
def raw_stdin():
    """Switches stdin to a non-buffering, non-echoing mode,
    handing keystrokes directly to the program as soon as they're 
    received and printing nothing to the terminal."""
    import termios as t
    f = t.tcgetattr(stdin)
    f[3] &= ~(t.ICANON|t.ECHO)
    t.tcsetattr(stdin, t.TCSANOW, f)

raw_stdin()

for i in range(10000000):
    #sleep(.334)
    stdin.read(1)
    print(i)
```

If I hit any key regularly, i.e. with the same time intervals between strokes down to the nearest 10ms or so, I get regular outputs, with zero hesitations. This proves the terminal is more than responsive enough, and that what I'm trying to do is possible. I have a hard time imagining the computer can't do something I can do with my left index finger.

I think it might have something to do with my linux kernel. I'd be interested to know what happens if this is run in windows, or on other linux kernels.

Comment: "If I hit any key regularly, i.e. with exactly the same number of milliseconds between strokes" LOL! You never did that

Comment: I don't need your mockery. And yeah it's more like 10ms. A regular beat with 10ms accuracy isn't that hard to do with your finger.

Comment: Your code prints sequential numbers. How are you measuring the delay between each line?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154867/real-time-processes-scheduling-in-linux&ved=0ahUKEwi7ktGF6v7XAhVq4oMKHWkPAVkQjjgIMjAE&usg=AOvVaw2_Kr6rSrPFmZV2_u39gyBE

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: tldr; it's not possible for a computer to give on screen feedback with 10ms accuracy. Frames usually top out around 16-17ms,  and then you add another 10-68ms for the pixels to hit the screen. So from code->pixels is 12-78ms delay. Computers cant provide visual feedback more accurate than that. Considering we can't even notice that in shooters, that means people can't notice delays of up to ~78ms, which means any claim of a beat more accurate than that is dubious at best.

Comment: Fine then, 78 ms. My implementation doesn't come anywhere near that in its present form. There are regularly 1 second delays.

Comment: Also, 78ms delays are very noticeable, under the right circumstances, especially audio delays, but also video delays. 78ms a/v skew is easily noticeable. Try playing two audio pulses 78 ms apart if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was my terminal all along (xfce4-terminal). There's a bug in it that messes up realtime output. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744798/1840698 for more.